# Cannot open database "MyBase" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'domain\User'

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, database-connection

```
string connectionString ="Server=localhost;Database=StudentRate;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=False;";
```

I have problem with connection, general with user databases, I can't connection to any.
[Property of login and user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkFGs.png). I try every way, but problem wasnt's solved.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding below string in your connection string it would help

```
Server=localhost;Database=StudentRate;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true
```